# Paper.js distance between point and path

Tags: javascript, path, point, paperjs

Is it possible to get distance between paper point and path?

```
const point = new Point([100, 200]);
const path = new Path();

path.strokeColor = 'black';
path.add(new Point(30, 30));
path.add(new Point(100, 100));
```

Answer (score 10):

`point.getDistance(path.getNearestPoint(point))` will get you the distance between the point in question and the nearest point to it on the path.